# Em programação, o que é o modelo de atores?

Tags: arquitetura-de-software, concorrência, microsserviços, sistemas-distribuídos, modelo-de-atores

Tenho um colega de trabalho que é apologista do *actor model* (modelo de atores, em português). Em linhas gerais ele parece tratar-se duma arquitetura de software para ser aplicada em sistemas distribuídos ou na *cloud*.

Por aquilo que percebi o conceito é que há vários atores e cada qual responsabiliza-se por completar determinada tarefa. Pareceu-me ser algo muito idêntico a microserviços mesmo.

Podem esclarecer melhor o que é de fato o modelo de atores?
(Normalmente não são permitidas perguntas adicionais, mas se puderem detalhar porque é que o modelo ator é diferente de microserviços, eu agradeço).

Comment: A resposta abaixo atendeu sua necessidade?

Comment: @MurilloGoulart Em parte. Estou á procura de outras respsotas. Nao me parece que uma resposta com um copy paste integral seja aceitável, mas essa é a minha opiniao...

Comment: Você já compreende os conceitos de sistemas distribuidos?

Comment: @Intruso Apenas duma forma superficial.

Comment: Meu receito é que exista confusão entre as definições específicas dos padrões e suas aplicações em determinados frameworks. Exemplo disso é a citação do Azure, que utiliza mas, não necessariamente 'dita' o padrão. Também existe ai uma confusão com a comparação de microservices, que deveria ser mais comparado com o modelo monolitico de arquitetura, mas, não necessariamente distribuido. A infraestrutura do framework (de forma que se mostre o padrão aplicado) está mais para o caso do Azure, talvez por isso, você esteja tendo dificuldades em expressar a pergunta de forma a obter respostas.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Os atores são componentes isolados, single-threads que encapsulam seu estado e comportamento. Isto é muito semelhante ao funcionamento dos serviços de mensagens convencionais, já que os atores recebem parâmetros de entrada por meio de mensagens.

MicroServices são componentes autônomos que por definição servem a uma única finalidade.
Em teoria, os atores são um ajuste perfeito para a implementação de ambientes em microServices.

A Azure Service Fabric enfatiza especialmente o modelo Ator definindo explicitamente Atores. Encontre mais informações sobre isso aqui: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-actors-introduction

Teoricamente, os atores podem ser vistos como microServices pequenos. Os atores são mensagens dirigidas, devem ter uma única responsabilidade (isto não está implícito no modelo, mas faz sentido), por isso há alguns equivalentes em comparação a microServices.
MicroServices podem suprir também outras responsabilidades. É importante lembrar que uma arquitetura de microserviços é principalmente uma decisão organizacional. Não se trata de dimensionar uma aplicação, mas sim de dimensionar uma organização de desenvolvimento. E alguns dos principais princípios de microservices, são coisas como independência de implantação, isolamento, tendo desenvolvimentos separados e ciclos de implantação, etc

Estas são coisas que você geralmente não começa apenas usando atores. Uma aplicação com base em ator ainda é uma base de código único e deve ser implantada como um único aplicativo (pelo menos com o estado atual dos quadros de ator disponíveis). Assim, enquanto os atores proporcionam escalonamento e melhor gerenciamento de concorrência e desenvolvimento distribuído, eles ainda não fornecem o nível de separação e isolamento que uma arquitetura baseada em microserviços fornece e, portanto, não atendem às mesmas necessidades.

De modo geral, em uma arquitetura de microserviços (MSA), o ator é o próprio microservice de acordo com http://usblogs.pwc.com/emerging-technology/what-is-microservices-architecture-think-ant-colonies-beehives-or-termite-mounds/

Answer (score 4):

**Modelo de Atores**
O Modelo de Atores, que teve seu desenvolvimento iniciado por Carl Hewitt 
(Mavadatt, 2002), é utilizado em algumas linguagens de programação como um método de 
programação concorrente. Inicialmente, o modelo proposto por Hewitt era uma comunidade 
de agentes, desenvolvido na linguagem  smalltalk, baseada na programação orientada a 
objetos onde, cada objeto era considerado como uma entidade ativa, recebendo, enviando e 
reagindo a mensagens. Tais objetos, bem  como as mensagens de interação, foram 
chamados de atores (Guy, 2003).

**Definições de Atores**
Segundo (Mavadatt, 2002),  atores são objetos concorrentes e independentes que 
interagem pelo envio assíncrono de mensagens. Para (Guy, 2003), um ator pode ter 
arbitrariamente muitos “conhecidos”, ou seja, ele pode “ter conhecimento” sobre outros 
atores e enviar mensagens a estes. (Lieberman, 1987) coloca que atores acabam com a 
distinção convencional entre dados e procedimentos, criando um processamento 
concorrente através da alocação dinâmica de recursos em uma máquina paralela. 
Na composição de tal objeto, tem-se que um ator encapsula estados, um conjunto de 
métodos e uma  thread ativa (Figura 1). Cada ator tem seu único endereço de correio, 
servindo como um alvo para o recebimento de mensagens, que é associado com buffers de 
comunicação ilimitados, formando assim uma fila para recebimento de mensagens. (Varela, 
2001).

Fonte: https://repositorio.ufsc.br/bitstream/handle/123456789/86260/203223.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y

Answer (score 3):

## Modelo de atores

O modelo de atores é um modelo matemático de computação concorrente apresentado em 1973. O conceito fundamental do modelo é que tudo é um ator, sendo ele a unidade mais básica de operação.

[image]

Esse modelo de concorrência, se destaca pois não compartilha estado entre os atores; os atores podem estar distribuídos em outras máquinas; e tem um conceito de tratamento de erros muito interessante: o ator morre. O estado não sendo compartilhado, cria um ambiente mais controlado.

### Atores

São o átomo do modelo de atores. Ele quem recebe mensagens e reage a elas de alguma forma.

Um ator sozinho não tem valor, pois depende de outro para mandar/receber mensagens. Formigas sozinhas não sobrevivem.

[image]

Essa entidade pode receber mensagens, e com as mensagens que recebe, pode:

1. Mandar mensagens para outros atores
2. Criar atores
3. Modificar seu estado para a próxima mensagem recebida

### Caixa de correio

As mensagens enviadas para um ator são guardadas numa caixa de entrada (*mailbox*) e são processadas uma a uma (FIFO).

### Distribuição

As representações do modelo de atores também prevê que o sistema deve ser distribuído. Não importa se estou mandando a mensagem para um ator que está rodando em outra máquina. Isso é importante quando falamos de escala horizontal.

A linguagem de programação que é fortemente associada com o modelo de atores é o [Erlang](http://erlang.org), mas que só surgiu 13 anos depois do modelo de atores. No universo Java temos o [Akka](https://akka.io) e o no Python o [Pykka](https://github.com/jodal/pykka). Isso mostra que esse modelo não está limitado às linguagens funcionais, como muitas vezes é pensado.

## Microsserviços

O microsserviço é um estilo de arquitetura para desenvolver uma aplicação como uma suite de serviços menores, cada uma rodando em processos separados e se comunicando com mecanismos como HTTP. Por mais que haja uma semelhança na divisibilidade das entidades entre o modelo de atores e os microsserviços, eles não são intercambiáveis.

Quando fala-se em modelo de atores, fala em diferentes processos representando atores que se comunicam com mensagens de forma direta. Quando fala-se em microsserviços, fala em diferentes backends com diferentes responsabilidades se comunicando via uma protocolo, como HTTP.